# Is there a list of "commands" for accessing network locations like "\\host\c$"?

Tags: networking, windows-explorer

I don't even know how this is called, but I would like to explorer more the options of "commands" I can access network from windows explorer like "\host\c$" to access the C drive of the host I am referencing too

what are other options I have besides accessing a particular drive using c$?

thanks

Comment: So I think you are asking for a list of known built-in native Windows Commands that run with UNC paths explicitly, correct? You could likely use any command and for those that do not support it then use [PUSHD](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) and [POPD](http://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) or [NET USE](http://ss64.com/nt/net_use.html) to map a drives, etc. For example, one that does NOT work with UNC paths is [FORFILES](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html)... In this case I've always had good success with pushd and popd and then pointing to the directory for the UNC path mounted with command arguments.

Comment: To better understand UNC paths just look over: http://compnetworking.about.com/od/windowsnetworking/g/unc-name.htm and look over: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg465305.aspx. . . I'm also not sure if you are looking for a command line "command" or what you mean when you say **"I can access network from windows explorer"** as if you're talking about Windows Explorer and its GUI, then I'm not certain why you need "commands" so please clarify if you can. I'll be happy to add a detailed answer if I can but give me your thoughts on this.